# How to create an error callback when a Jquery AJAX request fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making ajax requests using the following format:

```
$post('url', {someData:true}, myCallbackFunction, 'json);
```

The problem is, if on the server side any status code other than 200 is returned, the callback function is never called.

For example, if the user's session has timed out, I want to return 401 (unauthorized) as the status code, alongwith a JSON object as result which has an error message. But, unless the status code is 200, the callback function doesn't get called.

Any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: Try using [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) and [`.fail()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/), or even just `.fail()` if your success callback is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function errorCallback(response){
    alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText );
}
$.post('url', {someData:true}, myCallbackFunction, 'json').fail(errorCallback);
```

See [jquery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for more details.

Comment: this one works, but i want to get the JSON response returned by the server to be passed into the error callback. Any idea how to get the server response passed as an argument into the error callback?

Comment: `.fail(function(result)
                {
                    myErrorCallback(result.responseJSON);
                }` worked. `responseText` should work for normal / non json response.s